# Excel: Index and match with single criteria with multiple coulmns/rows

Tags: excel

```
Group  A  B  C  D  E
       1  2  3  4  5
       6  7  8  9  10
       11 12 13 14 15
```

I am looking for a index and match formula which I can show "9" belongs to the group "D".
Index(A1:E1,match("9",A2:E4,0))
Match can only search one column or row. Are there anyways to search multiple columns/rows?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX(1:1,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN(A2:E4)/(A2:E4 = 9),1))
```

Comment: It worked on excel! Thank you! can you use this in the google sheet too?

Comment: @user10901042 No, that is a different question.  You asked for Excel and as such this answered you question, please mark as correct by clicking the check mark next to the answer.